Connect to the database with DataSource class "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource". Integrated authentication failed
I'm trying to connect from webmethodsV10.7 (runs in Linux) to a remote hosted SQL Server via Windows authentication (that is user setup is done in Windows authentication using Active Directory for the SQL Server database). The SQL driver I use supports the database version.
I have copied the driver and *.dll files in

wm107/IntegrationServer/instances/DEV/packages/WmJDBCAdapter/code/jars
wm107/IntegrationServer/instances/DEV/packages/WmJDBCAdapter/code/jars/static
wm107/IntegrationServer/instances/DEV/lib/jars

I have set the following properties:
encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=javaKerberos;authentication=NotSpecified;

but still I get the following error:

Adapter Runtime (Connection): Unable to create new connection
supervisionOrders:somssqlDBConn. [ADA.1.204] Cannot connect to the
database with DataSource class
"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource". Integrated
authentication failed.
ClientConnectionId:ba9f0b27-f875-439d-84e6-77787d6e5a4e

Does anyone know what is wrong here?
UPDATE
If I add following properties:
encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true;integratedSecurity=true;authentication=NotSpecified;

I then get the following error:

This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load authentication DLL mssql-jdbc_auth-12.8.1.x64

I use sqljdbc_12.8.1.0 driver for SQL Server 2016 which is supported
Can we use that *.dll file in linux OS ?

How is the Kerberos setup configured on Linux? (i.e.: has kinit been run successfully?) Are you passing any -D... switches via the Java commandline so that the process knows where to find the Kerberos ticket?

@AlwaysLearning NO, i havent start server with Kerberoes setting. I saw in some posts for windows based authentication with remote mssql, we need to add that extra property..SO added but it didnt work..I tried adding useNTLMv2=true property too..but no luck. I updated my quetsion with new set of errors..

@AlwaysLearning Can we use //Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load authentication DLL mssql-jdbc_auth-12.8.1.x64// *.dll file in linux  to authenticate to remote mssql server via windows auth?

Did you follow the guide on microsoft jdbc page on how to connect using windows auth from linux

@siggemannen Can i get the correct link? i followed different different guides..

it's google.com and then microsoft jdbc windows auth linux .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ntlm-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 looks somewhat promising

You should be looking at Kerberos Authentication, not NTLM authentication. NTLM is a legacy protocol (v2 was introduced in 2000) and may be disabled. MS discourages its use since 2010. If the Linux client and the database server are in the same Kerberos domain you'll be able to connect without specifying credentials. Many of the Kerberos instructions in the link are about Kerberos in general, not SQL Server specifically

You can also connect by specifying the credentials in the connection string

@siggemannen I used as NTLM//encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true;authenticationScheme=NTLM;integratedSecurity=true;useNTLMv2=true// and getting Login failed for user 'domain\USERNAME'. But same user with password can be loggedn in via mssql management console using windows authentication

@PanagiotisKanavos I used Kerberoes //encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true;authenticationScheme=javaKerberos;integratedSecurity=true;// getting Integrated authentication failed....aused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7))

Did you check the docs on how to specify the credentials? You're trying to 1) connect to Kerberos and 2) use the Kerberos account to connect to SQL. There are no credentials in the connection string you just posted so the Linux machine must already be connected to Kerberos. Which probably isn't the case. The docs show that jdbc:sqlserver://servername=server_name;encrypt=true;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;userName=user;password=<password>;realm=REALM will connect

@PanagiotisKanavos Username db password and all there I provide via UI option( i didnt add that screenshot) only I add the extraproperties here to figure it out that, whether I provide correct propertie or not..

I made it to work with following properties;
encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true;authenticationScheme=NTLM;integratedSecurity=true;useNTLMv2=true 

